# How to concatenate two object which are based on tuple

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, operator-overloading, variadic-templates

I have a class template which is based on a `std::tuple` and only consist of that tuple.
How can I concatenate two object of this class template in order to have all the tuple member of both class as an object of the same class template.
Using `tuple_cat` does not works, probably because the types are not tuple

```
template<typename...Ts>
class foo : private std::tuple<Ts...> {
public:
    foo(Ts...vs) : std::tuple<Ts...>(vs...){}
    //  .
    //  .
    //  .
};



template<typename...T1s, typename...T2s>
foo<T1s..., T2s...> operator+(const foo<T1s...>& foo1, const foo<T2s...>& foo2){
    //  return std::tuple_cat(foo1, foo2); // this does not work
    //  what should be here?
}

foo<int, float, const char*> obj1(1, 1.23, "string1");
foo<const char*, float, int> obj2("string2" , 1.23, 1);

foo<int, float, const char*, const char*, float, int> obj3 = obj1 + obj2;// I want to do this by overloading of operator +
```

Comment: Step 1: add an `const std::tuple<Ts...> &me() const { return *this; }` class member. Step 2: invoke `tuple_cat`, passing a pair of `me()`s to it, and define your `operator+`'s return type as `auto`. Step 3: mission accomplished.

Comment: Instead of having `foo` derive from `std::tuple`, give `foo` a priave `std::tuple` member object.  Then `operator +` can be `return std::tuple_cat(foo1.tuple_member, foo2.tuple_member);`.  this does also require you create a constructor that allows you to pass a `std::tuple` to `foo` that initialize the tuple member directly.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik ```foo``` cannot be constructed from the base alone! he should also use ```Std::apply```. Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you inherit privately, the `std::tuple` base is not accessible to `operator+`, so you need to fix that one way or another. I think the easiest way is to make `operator+` a friend of `foo`. Then, with the addition of a (private) constructor from `std::tuple`, you can just use `std::tuple_cat` on the correct types (through references or `static_cast`):

```
template<typename... Ts>
class foo : private std::tuple<Ts...> {
    explicit foo(std::tuple<Ts...>&& tuple) : std::tuple<Ts...>(std::move(tuple)) {}

public:
    foo(Ts...vs) : std::tuple<Ts...>(vs...){}

    template<typename... T1s, typename... T2s>
    friend foo<T1s..., T2s...> operator+(foo<T1s...> const& foo1, foo<T2s...> const& foo2);
};

template<typename... T1s, typename... T2s>
foo<T1s..., T2s...> operator+(foo<T1s...> const& foo1, foo<T2s...> const& foo2) {
    std::tuple<T1s...> const& tuple1 = foo1;
    std::tuple<T2s...> const& tuple2 = foo2;
    return foo(std::tuple_cat(tuple1, tuple2));
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cGzT6E5fM)

If you don't want the additional constructor, you can use `std::apply` to pass all the elements to the main constructor instead:

```
template<typename... T1s, typename... T2s>
foo<T1s..., T2s...> operator+(foo<T1s...> const& foo1, foo<T2s...> const& foo2) {
    std::tuple<T1s...> const& tuple1 = foo1;
    std::tuple<T2s...> const& tuple2 = foo2;
    auto make_foo = [](auto&&... arg) { return foo(std::move(arg)...); };
    return std::apply(make_foo, std::tuple_cat(tuple1, tuple2));
}
```

Comment: OK sorry, it looks like I was wrong. However this ```std::tuple<int> tp{12};
foo foo1{std::move(tp)};``` still gives error because it is private

Comment: @AKL Yes, it's private, because OP might not want to give users access to the conversion. I don't see the problem.

Comment: Just consider this  ```auto f1(){return 12;}
auto f2(){return std::tuple{12, 13};}
foo foo1 = f1();
foo foo2 = f2();
```
construction of ```foo1``` is OK, while construction of the ```foo2``` gives the error that I am speaking about.
Maybe OP wants to also have ```foo<std::tuple<int, int>>``` type, possible. And having the private constructor is making it impossible!

Comment: OK not impossible but harder than other cases

Comment: Fair enough, you have to specify the template arguments unless the constructor is marked `explicit`. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Still you can achieve this functionality by employing `std::tuple_cat`, but you also need to use `std::apply`.

Because the `tuple` base of `foo` is inaccessible from outside `foo`, you have two options:

As Nelfeal mentioned in the first method you can declare the `operator+` as friend of `foo` class template.

Second method requires that you declare any other `foo` class template as a friend class template, which might make things easier for other possible methods, which involve another `foo`. And have the `operator+` as the class method.

```
template<typename...Ts>
class foo : private std::tuple<Ts...> {
    template<typename ... T2s>
    friend class foo;
public:
    foo(Ts...vs) : std::tuple<Ts...>(vs...){}
    
template<typename ... T2s>
    foo<Ts..., T2s...> operator+(const foo<T2s...>& other) const
    {
        const auto& base1 = *static_cast<const std::tuple<Ts ...> *>(this);
        const auto& base2 = static_cast<const std::tuple<T2s ...>&>(other);
        const auto& base = std::tuple_cat(base1, base2);
        auto pass = [](auto&& ... refs){return foo<Ts..., T2s...>(std::move(refs) ...);};
        return std::apply(pass, base);
    }

    //  .
    //  .
    //  .
};
```

**Explanation**:

`base1` and `base2` are simply the `tuple` base of `foo1` and `foo2`. And because they are `tuple`, now you can use `std::tuple_cat` on them to get the concatenated `tuple` base for the result.
`std::apply` applies the the given function (first argument) on all the elements of the given `tuple` (second argument). The lambda function, `pass` simply creates a `foo` based on given arguments.

Now you can use it like:

```
foo<int, float, const char*> obj1(1, 1.23, "string1");
foo<const char*, float, int> obj2("string2" , 1.23, 1);

foo<int, float, const char*, const char*, float, int> obj3 = obj1 + obj2;
// or
auto obj4 = obj1 + obj2;
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the `operator+` overload is declared as a `friend` (a fairly common mistake of leaving out key parts of the question), rendering all of this a moot point. Additionally, the proposed cause makes a buch of redundant copies.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik agreed on both points, however OP might have some reasons not to have other constructors even as private constructor. However I changed my answer to cover your first point. Please take a look

Comment: You are still making unnecessary copies.

Comment: @Nelfeal I know, but this version of the class template is as close to the original version as possible. I think you should make the extra ```private``` constructor in your version of ```foo``` ```explicit```. Because if OP wanted to construct ```foo``` from a tuple, he would simply made that as the default constructor or as an additional constructor. Having it as a private constructor might give the inaccessibility error in some cases! For example in your version, ```foo``` can not be constructed from a single ```std::tuple``` object. And then compiler would issue an error

Comment: @AKL This has nothing to do with the additional constructor. `std::tuple<Ts ...>(*this)` creates a new `tuple` object, and it copies the elements from `*this`. You then take a reference to that temporary object.

Comment: @Nelfeal are you sure, I think ```Base(*this)``` (```std::tuple<Ts ...>(*this)``` in this case) only convert the object to ```base``` object , and not copying it. Even in this case, if I was wrong then it would have also worked without the ```friend``` declaration. Am I wrong?

Comment: There is no public conversion from `foo<Ts...>` to `std::tuple<Ts...>`, so you still need the `friend` declaration. Conversion to base class still makes a copy, though. [Just try it](https://godbolt.org/z/7q7bcsz49). You need to use a pointer or a reference to avoid performing a copy.

Comment: @Nelfeal Thanks a lot for your correction. I was thinking like that for ages. I edited my answer to cover your point and to avoid unnecessary copies. Please take a look.

Comment: `static_cast<const std::tuple<Ts...>&>(other)` achieves the same thing as  `*static_cast<const std::tuple<Ts...>*>(&other)` with fewer symbols. Also you duplicated two lines of code for no reason.